# How to get records from has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models `Hotel` and `Theme` and I have applied `has_and_belongs_to_many` association on it.

My migration is

```
class CreateHotelsThemesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :hotels_themes, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :hotel
        t.references :theme
    end
    add_index :hotels_themes, [:hotel_id, :theme_id]
    add_index :hotels_themes, :hotel_id
  end

  def down
    drop_table :hotels_theme
  end
end
```

And models are:

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :theme_names
  has_and_belongs_to_many :hotels
end



class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hotel_name, :stars, :location
  validates :hotel_name, :stars, :location, :presence => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :thumes
end
```

Where some records are:

```
theme
=> #<Theme id: 5, theme_names: "Friends", created_at: "2013-08-24 20:13:00", updated_at: "2013-08-24 20:13:00">

    hotel
=> #<Hotel id: 2, hotel_name: "vijay shree1", stars: "2", location: "South Goa", created_at: "2013-08-24 15:59:53", updated_at: "2013-08-24 15:59:53">
```

When I run

```
>> theme.hotels
=> [#<Hotel id: 2, hotel_name: "vijay shree1", stars: "2", location: "South Goa", created_at: "2013-08-24 15:59:53", updated_at: "2013-08-24 15:59:53">]
```

working but when I run

```
>> hotel.themes
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `themes' for #<Hotel:0x007f6cd007c080>>
```

I am not getting why this is happening I have used has_and_belongs_to_many association. Thank in advance for help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a typo: `has_and_belongs_to_many :thumes`.

I think this is a cause of your problem